# Reading osx screenshot image in sandbox

Tags: objective-c, macos, screenshot, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I want to get the screenshot triggered by different osx shortcuts. So i add an observer with `kMDItemIsScreenCapture`. Following code was used to add observer.

```
_query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
[_query setDelegate:self];
[_query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kMDItemIsScreenCapture = 1"]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenshotQueryUpdated:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:_query];
[_query startQuery];
```

Implementation of `screenshotQueryUpdated` is as follow:

```
NSMetadataItem *item = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:(NSString *)kMDQueryUpdateAddedItems] lastObject];
if (item) {
    NSString *screenShotPath = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemPathKey];
    NSData* temp = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:screenShotPath];
    // More code....
}
```

Problem is i can not read file at **screenShotPath** in `sandbox` mode. So what is the right way to get screenshot file in application with sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `NSOpenPanel` to ask the user for access to either this file or the folder containing the screenshots. You will be able to then create a [security scoped bookmark](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16) to get access on the same resource on subsequent launches of your app.

Comment: So is this the only way, i can not do it without `security scoped bookmark`, like getting user's permission in this will break the UX

Comment: yes. sorry. Security and UX are usually counterparts.